# Method to accept one class object or another class object

Tags: java

I have two methods like the following

```
private List<Long> getIds(String name, List<Cat> cats) {
    List<Long> catIds = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Cat cat : cats) {
        if (cat.getName().equals(name)) catIds.add(cat.getId());
    }
    return catIds;
}

private List<Long> getIds(String name, List<Dog> dogs) {
    List<Long> dogIds = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Dog dog : dogs) {
        if (dog.getName().equals(name)) dogIds.add(dog.getId());
    }
    return dogIds;
}
```

My cat and dog class are as follows

```
public class Cat {
    String name;
    Long id;
    // additional variables
    // getters and setters
}

public class Dog {
    String name;
    Long id;
    // additional variables
    // getters and setters
}
```

Just to avoid redundancy, I wanted to convert the above two methods to a single generic method.

I tried the following

```
private List<Long> getIds(String name, List<T> objects) {
    List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T object : objects) {
        if (object.getName().equals(name)) ids.add(object.getId());
    }
    return ids;
}
```

But it does not work out as it complains that the generic T does not have `getName` or `getId`

Here `Cat` and `Dog` are in-built java classes. As a result I **CANNOT** perform inheritance and provide a super class `Animal` for them with `name` and `id` as data variables.

Is there any way I could accomplish merging the two above methods without implementing inheritance?

Comment: make Animal interface containing getName. implement that in Cat and Dog. in your getIds method, change to ? extends Animal

Comment: You might also want to have a look at this [recipe for duck typing in Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Java) from Wikipedia...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've got that you cannot use any type of inheritance. Here is a short solution with Reflection API then:

```
private static List<Long> getIds(String name, List<?> objects) {
    List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object object : objects) {
        try {
            Method getName = null;
            Method getId = null;

            for (Method method : object.getClass().getMethods()) {
                if (method.getName().equals("getName") && method.getReturnType().equals(String.class) && method.getParameterTypes().length == 0) {
                    getName = method;
                }
                if (method.getName().equals("getId") && method.getReturnType().equals(Long.class) && method.getParameterTypes().length == 0) {
                    getId = method;
                }
                if (getName != null && getId != null && getName.invoke(object).equals(name)) {
                   ids.add((Long) getId.invoke(object));
                   break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    return ids;
}
```

Comment: Some suggestions: Use `equals` to compare the strings, and raise an `IllegalArgumentException` in case the class does not have that attribute. Also, `List<Object>` is too strict; use `List<?>`.

Comment: thanks for equals - my mistake, wrote this code too fast)

Comment: Also, can you provide me example, where any instance in the input objects list would not have accessible equals method? Sounds interesting

Comment: With this approach, how could I know (if I want to call `getIds`) that the objects in the list I give must have at least two methods `public String getName()` and `public long getId()` ?

Comment: you can't know for sure, what is in list and which methods it has. That's why "NoSuchMethod" exception may be produced and must be caught (see "catch" clause). I can write more sofisticated example, but there is no ideal way to solve author's problem without interface - you need to make trade-offs to deal with code duplication in this situation :)

Comment: And that's exactly what's bothering me with this solution. It exists an ideal solution (type-safe), see tobias_k's answer.

Comment: his solution for java 8 is good, but not ideal too - you must process every groups of instances in input object list by specific approach calling method like: getIds("some name", listOfCats, Cat::getName, Cat::getId); getIds("some name", listOfDogs, Dog::getName, Dog::getId); and so on. And what if we have input list of ANY objects? Not only Cats and Dogs - not even animals. My method call is very simple: getIds(name, inputListOfAnything)

Comment: To be frank, I am trying to optimize the code. That would mean a clean code with better efficiency and lesser number of LOC. The approach u showed me above is good enough. But it does not reduce the number of lines considerably.

Comment: I would love to have something small and concise like @tobias_k 's answer, but with Java 7.

Comment: @PhilipJohn To be honest, personally I would go with this answer, with the exception that I would also throw an `IllegalArgumentException` in case the method can not be found, instead of silently ignoring elements that do not have those methods. I'm afraid this is as close as it gets to [Duck Typing in Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Java)

Comment: by the way, I fixed code for unnecessary NoSuchMethod exceptions (may be slow for massive lists processing) and added some filtration by method signature (more confident, what exactly we try to invoke). But I don't know any way to make this reflection code more concise in java 7 :( And the only alternative - code generation tools - performs even worse

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility: If you are using Java 8, you could pass in the getter methods for name and ID as additional parameters into the method. This is type-safe and does neither need reflection nor modifications to the original classes.

```
private <T> List<Long> getIds(String name, List<T> objects, Function<T, String> getName, Function<T, Long> getId) {
    List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T object : objects) {
        if (getName.apply(object).equals(name)) {
            ids.add(getId.apply(object));
        }
    }
    return ids;
}
```

Or shorter, using streams:

```
private <T> List<Long> getIds(String name, List<T> objects, Function<T, String> getName, Function<T, Long> getId) {
    return objects.stream().filter(o -> getName.apply(o).equals(name))
            .map(getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Long> ids = getIds("some name", listOfCats, Cat::getName, Cat::getId);
```

Of course, while this way the *body* of the method is the same for all the cases, you have to *call* it in different ways, depending on the input. For this, you could provide an entry method, calling the other method in the appropriate way or raising an Exception in case the type is wrong.

```
private List<Long> getIds(String name, List<?> objects) {
    if (objects.size() == 0) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    if (objects.get(0) instanceof Cat) {
        return getIds(name, (List<Cat>) objects, Cat::getName, Cat::getId);
    }
    if (objects.get(0) instanceof Dog) {
        ...
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("List containing unsupported type!");
}
```

Comment: This was a very good approach. But my current project has to be in Java 7. And the client wants it to be Java 7. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a common interface for `Cat` and `Dog`, for example `Animal`.

Than you can pass a `List<Animal>` as parameter.

Comment: Op says `Here Cat and Dog are in-built java classes. As a result I CANNOT perform inheritance and provide a super class Animal for them with name and id as data variables.`

Comment: I edit my answer to show you another possible approach

Comment: @VinayVeluri ah.. I missed to see that

Comment: Hi.. I kind of know this approach.. but I would like to avoid changing my Cat or Dog class.

Comment: John, look at my reflection solution. Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

Can you just make an interface for both Dog and Cat?

```
interface animal {
    ...
    Long getId();
}

public class Cat implements Animal
public class Dog implements Animal
```

then your method would become

```
private List<Long> getIds(String name, List<Animal> animals) {
    List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Animal animal : animals) {
        ids.add(animal.getId());
    }
    return ids;
}
```

Regarding the in-built class you've mentioned, you can wrap them in another class and implements the interface(or superclass) describing the desired behavior.

I once had to provide same interface for `log4j` and `logback` event Object, they two are quite different definitely.

here the wrapper goes..

```
public abstract class EventWrapper {
    public abstract String getFormattedMessage();
}
```

And the child class which actually holds the in-built class

```
public class Log4jEvent extends EventWrapper {
    LoggingEvent event;

    public Log4jEvent(LoggingEvent event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedMessage() {
        if (event.getMessage() != null) {
            return event.getMessage().toString();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

LogbackEvent class is very similar to Log4jEvent class, and in other parts of the code, there are many method which receives argument type of EventWrapper. Maybe this case would help you develop your solution.

Comment: I cannot do that. I cannot edit the Cat or Dog classes

Comment: I saw it, you can just wrap them in your custom wrapper class. well..I'll add a sample from my experience.

Comment: @이승진 Interesting. so creating new classes extending the Cat and Dog classes and implement the Animal interface ?

Comment: I posted an example from my experience, very similar to the author's case.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Reflection API, if you can't change Cat and Dog classes.
Otherwise use interface Animal (or type casting)

Comment: In the case that a super-class is indeed not possible, I think this is the only way. But as it stands, this is not much more than a comment. Could you add some code?

Answer (score 0):

If it is no problem having some more lines within the method. What about this?

```java
private List<Long> getIds(String name, List<?> objects) {
    List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>();

    for (Object object : objects) {
        if(object instanceof Dog){
            Dog dog = (Dog) object;
            if (dog.getName().equals(name)) 
                ids.add(dog.getId());
        } else if (object instanceof Cat){
            Cat cat = (Cat) object;
            if (cat.getName().equals(name)) 
                ids.add(cat.getId());
        }
    }
    return ids;
}
```

A more generic approach would be this:

```java
private <T> List<Long> getIds(String name, List<T> objects, IdGetter<T> idGetter) {
    List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>();
    for (T object : objects) {
        Long id= idGetter.getId(object);
        if(id != null){
            ids.add(id);
        }
    }
    return ids;
}

public interface IdGetter<T> {
    Long getId(T object);
}
```

Comment: though it gets the job done, this does open the function to pass anything like List<Pencils> - not truly generics

Comment: Yes, but it will not provide anything wrong for other types. You might add an null return value or an exception in case of unexpected types.

Comment: Not wrong technically but what about time complexity.. you end up iterating the entire collection fully just to return an empty List

Comment: To be frank, I am trying to optimize the code. That would mean a clean code with better efficiency and lesser number of LOC. So, I would not prefer using `instanceof` and a not the second approach for sure.